# RootTools.deleteFileOrDirectory always returns false

Tags: android, android-file

I am using the RootTools library from [here](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools)

After granting root privileges to the app, I am trying to delete a file in the internal storage using Root.

```
deleteStatus = RootTools.deleteFileOrDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
```

The `deleteStatus` always turns out to be false and the file is also not deleted.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I am new with ROOT usage. I basically have a very few requirements in my app with ROOT.

1) I need to check if ROOT is available on the device. (RootTools.isRootAvailable())

2) I need to give a ROOT permission prompt to the user to GRANT root permission (RootTools.isAccessGiven())

3) Delete files and folders (RootTools.deleteFileOrDirectory)

Everything works perfectly, except the delete method. How can I do this using libsuperuser?

Comment: Can you paste the path to the file?

Comment: Yes, the path is /storage/emulated/0/logo_large_new.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RootTools isn't the greatest. Personally, I suggest going with [libsuperuser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser).

There are plenty of reasons why your file isn't being deleting. If you look at RootTools, it doesn't add quotes around the path. So, if your file contains whitespace then it will not be deleted.

From [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/blob/master/RootTools/src/com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.java#L431-433):

```
Command command = new Command(0, false, "rm -r " + target);
Shell.startRootShell().add(command);
commandWait(Shell.startRootShell(), command);
```

It should be:

```
Command command = new Command(0, false, "rm -r \"" + target + "\"");
Shell.startRootShell().add(command);
commandWait(Shell.startRootShell(), command);
```

---

**Edit:**

The path returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDir()` cannot be read in a shell. You will need to change the path before sending the command to the shell.

To fix this your can add the following static factory method to your project:

```
/**
 * The external storage path is not readable by shell or root. This replaces {@link
 * Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()} with the environment variable "EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
 *
 * @param file
 *         The file to check.
 * @return The original file (if it does not start with {@link
 * Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()}
 * or a file with the correct path.
 */
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public static File getFileForShell(File file) {
    String externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (!file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(externalStorage)) {
        return file;
    }
    String legacyStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    String path;
    if (legacyStorage != null) {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst(externalStorage, legacyStorage);
    } else {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst(externalStorage, "/sdcard");
    }
    return new File(path);
}
```

Then, when you call `RootTools.deleteFileOrDirectory(String target, boolean remountAsRw);` change the file path:

```
String path = getFileForShell(file).getAbsolutePath();
RootTools.deleteFileOrDirectory(path, true);
```

---

You don't need root access to delete files on internal storage. You need the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` declared in your manifest.

---

**libsuperuser**

To check if root access is available and show the root permission prompt, you could call the following method:

```
boolean isRooted = Shell.SU.available();
```

The library, libsuperuser, is not intended to do all the things RootTools attempts to do. If you choose to use libsuperuser you will need to send the commands to the shell.

An example of deleting a file with libsuperuser:

```
void delete(File file) {
    String command;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        command = "rm -r \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    } else {
        command = "rm \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    }
    Shell.SU.run(command);
}
```

Note that this does not mount the file system read/write or check if `rm` is available on the device (something RootTools does when you invoke `deleteFileOrDirectory`).

---

This is a lengthy answer. If you have further questions I would suggest reading the documentation for either library project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, if I need to migrate library at this point, then there is a lot of changes I will need to make. And libsuperuser seems a bit difficult for me to use. How can I modify the delete method in RootTools so that it works perfectly.

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub. I updated my answer. My answer should work since your file contains no spaces.

Comment: Actually, I am testing on internal storage. But users can have files on external SD card too and can have filenames with spaces too. Will this new method solve both the problems?

Comment: The method you gave me getFileForShell(), works like a charm. Should I be using it with files in the Internal Storage?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be used for files on internal storage. However, you can just do `file.delete()` if your app has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. I added more to my answer. Comments aren't intended for a conversation. Best of luck on your project!

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer. Helped me a lot. Actually, I am willing to use libsuperuser but I can't find much documentation on it on how to copy files, delete files and directories, etc. Moreover, I have to change a lot of code in my app. Any way I can fix the spaces problem in RootTools myself now?